# MessageFormat Formatting without Default Locale

Tags: java

I'm trying to fix the errors of forbidden apis. I had an error which says:

```
[forbiddenapis] Forbidden method invocation: java.text.MessageFormat#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object[]) [Uses default locale]
[forbiddenapis]   in org.a.b.MyClass (MyClass.java:813)
```

Which points to that:

```
logger.debug(MessageFormat.format("Added {0} documents", new Object[] { new Integer(count) }));
```

So, I've changed it to that:

```
logger.debug(MessageFormat.format("Added {0} documents", new Object[] { new Integer(count) }, Locale.ROOT));
```

However, error still exists. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

None of the static MessageFormat.format() implementations accept a Locale as an argument, especially as a last argument, as it would interfere with the Object... signature; the only way to set a locale is in the constructor, so if you are keen to use a static format() method, you would have to 'roll your own' somewhere with code similar to this:

```
public static String format(Locale loc, String pattern, Object ... arguments) 
{
  MessageFormat temp = new MessageFormat(pattern, loc);
  return temp.format(arguments);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Define a `MessageManager` with `private final Local` field

```
var mf = new MessageFormat(pattern, locale);
return mf.format(args, new StringBuffer(), null).toString();
```

This is, defacto, java i18n standard

Reference implementation: https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/main/java/org/apache/catalina/tribes/util/StringManager.java#L153,L155

---

**NOTE:** Avoid calling mf.format(argArray).

That would inject the entire array to the placeholder #0 ([src](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/text/Format.java#L157))